# Where do I code html?

Tags: html, css

So I recently finished the *HTML and CSS* course at [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/), and I want to practice coding with html and css. My problem though, is that I don't know where to start. I've been searching around to try and find the information I need, but I can't find anything. I kind of feel like it's so obvious noone's ever needed to ask, but I don't know, so here I am, asking.

While searching for the answer to this question, I could only find sites that teach how to use html and css, like Codecademy, and sites that let you test html code like [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro), but no sites that let you practice html *and* CSS.

**Here's my question:**

Are HTML and CSS created as .html and .css files on my computer?

Comment: Start Here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/ Practice Here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: One question per question please. Also, since you don't have a specific code-related question this really isn't the place to ask your questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If you are looking for some advice on starting out, I'd recommend searching your favorite search engine for some tutorials or grab a book.

Comment: Those 3 questions are pretty generic and there are multiple answers to each of them.

Comment: Don't discourage this guy tho. I'm adding an answer.

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh - I'm not looking to discourage the user (see my comment above), however it's not SO's job to answer every user that comes with their hat in hand, asking multiple broad questions which will solicit many different opinions.

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh he should be discouraged already since the first comment suggested w3fools...

Comment: @j08691 I'll take this into note for future posts. I figured this fell under "software tools commonly used by programmers" since I am asking where programmers code in html. Maybe I misunderstood it though. Also, I used Codecademy to learn it in the first place, I just need to practice it.

Comment: @Spyfiend13 it's pretty typical that new users (including me) don't know how to question properly. Other people suggest how to question, and you just take that and learn from it. But sometimes I get offended because those 'suggestions' look very discouraging, and I get scared to ask questions as a newbie. I hope you didn't get offended this time.

Answer (score 4):

You should ask new question for each of the questions you posted.

> Where do I code html?

1. You can use any text editor.  Try [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) - download the app for your operating system and install.
2. Create a new file, saving it with the file exetension `.html`.  Be sure you saved the file in an easy to find location - like you would with any word processing document or spreadsheet.
3. Open a browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).
4. Click and drag your new HTML file into the tab window.
5. Make some changes in your HTML file.
6. Refresh your browser tab.
7. You're now on your way to learning more about coding HTML in your local environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can create HTML, CSS and JS files on your hard drive and simply open up the HTML file by double-clicking it (or opening it directly through the browser's file menu).

Typically these files are stored on an HTTP server that provides content when asked... but for your purposes to practice HTML and CSS, you can simply save the files on your hard-drive and open them from there.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, they are (but CSS can be stored on a server as well, see 2.). You can then open the HTML file you're editing in any browser and see the output.
2. You can include CSS in your HTML file by using:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-your.css">`

The path to CSS file can also lead to an online server, if the CSS file is stored there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: 1. This is not necessarily true 2. What about including CSS directly in the HTML document(which is where I would suggest a beginner starts)?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think to answer is:

**Are CSS and HTML coded in a file on one's computer?**
Yes

**If so, how is the CSS connected to the HTML, and how are these connected to a website?**
In the HTML file you specify which CSS files will be used in your page (I'm assuming you know what CSS files are for). The web browsers like Internet Explorer, Firefox or Chrome, read the HTML code and produce the sites you see anywhere.

If you are only practicing basic HTML:

1. Open notepad (Windows+R, type "notepad", enter)
2. Write some code like the found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp
3. Save your file with .html extension
4. Open it in your web browser by just double clicking the file

**EDIT**. Check this other example to see how to reference the CSS files http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp.

You only need to put your HTML file and CSS file in a folder in your computer, you don't need go to any site to practice this because HTML and CSS code is interpreted directly by your web browser.

Comment: Notepad will want to save your file with a "txt" extension. If you use quotes around the name (`"mypage.html"`) you can get around that.

Answer (score 1):

> Are CSS and HTML coded in a file on one's computer?

**yes and no.**

Basically CSS can be anywhere; your computer, your server, someone else's server, etc.

Your Chrome blocks some local sources for security reasons, but Firefox handles them pretty well. If you have a static website (that does not involve with any database), you can just create a directory and make html, css, and javascript files and open with Firefox to test.

Otherwise, get hosting services like godaddy, or get a server like Amazon Web Services and put them in there.

> If so, how is the CSS connected to the HTML, and how are these connected to a website?

Typically, this is how people do.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- your body... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

> If not, where are HTML and CSS coded for use on the web?

This was answered above.

Answer (score 1):

CSS and HTML are not things that need to be installed on your computer, you just need to create a file with the .html extension, put some code in it and open it with a browser. The browser interprets it automatically, the same goes for CSS. To create HTML pages for practice, all you need to install is an IDE to edit your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - everyone has to start somewhere and I'm going to assume you are a novice so if any of this information is too basic, please excuse it.

There are tiers to consider here....First let's break down what the languages do - I'm going to talk about additional languages because I see people already talking about servers and scripting to so I'm going to try and tie this all together for you. I started self taught and learned a lot of hard lessons so hopefully this add's a little bit of an advantage to the learning curve.

**SERVER** Think of a server as a computer. It run's slightly different software but the principles are the same. It's only job is to store code, interpret it and present it when called. A very popular server software that you'll find is **apache** so let's focus on this for now. **Windows is not a server** and can't be used as a server. However, it's possible to edit a server with windows and it's possible to run server software on top of windows just like any other application. You'll hear references to WAMP, LAMP, XAMPP and a bunch of other acronyms but for now you just need to know why they exist and what they do. **A server is not required to write and produce html and css documents**

**HTML** The primary purpose of HTML is to tell a web browser what it's looking at. You'll see a lot of HTML4 vs HTML5 and a ton of other arguments that won't make a lot of sense up front. The important thing to remember about HTML is that it is the framework for everything website related. A lot of people will argue that other languages are more important for one reason or another but without html, none of the other languages matter at all. Whatever you know about this is fine for now. Start small and work your way up.

**CSS** Is amazing. CSS3 is the current standard but there are still some things that are not cross browser compatible. That's a story for another day but the basics are the same everywhere. You define your classes, id's and elements then tell them how they're going to look. The more you get in to CSS the more you'll realize how amazing it really is. It's useful on a lot of levels and plays a big part in some scripting languages. The biggest thing to remember about CSS is that you should write as little as possible. The more rules you write, the more chance there is for overlapping and something you wrote 3 files ago on line 463 is going to dominate a new rule you just wrote. Try and write as much as possible in classes too so you can really make your code globally usable.

**PHP/ASP** These are just two of the more popular languages that are considered back end languages. When you're thinking of a website, break it down like this. Front end = Browser, Back end = server. Anything that PHP does is on the browser side. As an end user of a website, you'll rarely see it but it's a major component. This is relevant because as you grow, you'll wonder about trying your hand at a back end scripting language. That's great but that's when you're going to start getting in to servers and such so I'm sure you'll hear a lot about the benefits of it but for now, just stay focused on the basics until you're comfortable.

**Javascript/jQuery** Again, this is just two popular examples of the many scripting languages that are available on the client side(the browser). These languages can generally be viewed(and edited) by the end user. They are extremely useful for changing pages content without reloading the page and they can talk to the server languages as well. Again, get more comfortable first with your basics before branching out here but with the references you're bound to receive to these languages as you learn, it's helpful to know what they do and why.

**Editor** To edit html you can **absolutely use any text editor**. Word, notepad, notepad++, sublime-text, wordpad...literally anything that saves in a standard text format. As long as the extension is html, css, etc. The editors geared towards programming offer a lot of features and benefits as compared to the basic editors available in your windows/mac setup. Try your hand at a few different ones and see what suits your taste. You can write one file of html, download the programs and right click to open with each program to see the differences. Personally I recommend Notepad++ but to each his own.

**Why is my answer so long?** I know this is a majorly overkill answer to your question however I also know how hard it was for me to get started in this field without some very basic knowledge. This should be enough to get you off and running and hopefully help out when you encounter some unfamiliar territory. In the future, if you find yourself looking to get in to the server/scripting world, let me know and I'll pass along a write up I did on setting up xampp for windows.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout setting up a WAMP, LAMP, MAMP server depending on your platform (W) Windows, (M) Mac, (L) Linux.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/288158-easy-lamp-server-installation

https://www.mamp.info/en/

Then in your respective directory (html_public, Sites, wherever) you will have a local server environment where you can develop locally.

I use the Sites/ setup on a mac

css and javascript are usually linked in the head section of an html document.

You will need a editor -  I recommend looking at Sublime Text or Atom.io

If you just want to play around for a while before attempting your own projects, you can build on sandboxes like http://codepen.io

Answer (score 0):

You need a text editor to practice your code I recommend downloading [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Its free, in sublime under view you can change syntax which is the language you are programming in you can set it to html or css or any other language you desire.

The structure for "connecting" html and css is usually a simple folder like structure.

Create a folder called Website
In that folder you would have your html file(s) you can call it index.html 
Also in that folder you would have sub folder(s) for your CSS and JS but since you are just working with CSS now create a folder named css. This is where you will save your css file that could be called something like style.css

Here is a more through guide on folder and [directory structure](http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/web-development/creating-files-folder-structure-web-pages/).

Keep going with Codecademy and build your own projects in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at a good example. [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) is a good starting point and has some good practices for a project (in my opinoin). This may be a good reference for you to get a feeling of how the javascript and css files can be arranged and linked to. The website is static so you can open the index.html file with a browser to preview it. You can also make changes to the css and javascript files to see how this changes the index.html page.

https://html5boilerplate.com/

You're asking a very broad set of questions but hopefully there's quite a few good answers in here to point you in the right direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to have both HTML and CSS in one file using the style tags:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Text</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

However it is considered proper practice to use Cascading Style Sheets, which is probably what Code Academy used.

Answer (score 0):

**Are CSS and HTML coded in a file on one's computer?**
A: depends either you can create both css and html in one file or in different files. If you using lots of css code then everyone will suggest you to write them in different files and you can code them in someone's computer or on server.

**If so, how is the CSS connected to the HTML, and how are these connected to a website?**
A: you said that you have done html and course and you don't know who to add a css file to a html file. (Use Google sometimes) use this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) you Wil get you answer. After coding you can test them using your web development tool if you are developing in a tool. Else use your web browser to test.

I suggest you to visit websites as much as you can an use chrome tool to see how that website is done (you can only find front end parts.)